# How to handle session timeout in Spring-security 3.2

Tags: java, spring, session

I am new to spring security. I am trying to redirect the URL to login page on clicking any tab/link after session time out

I have below configuration in my security context

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
    secured-annotations="enabled">
    <!-- <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/> -->
</global-method-security>

<security:http pattern="/pages/common/UnAuthorized.html*"
    security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/resources/images/*" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/Logout.html*"
    security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/SessionTimeout.html*"
    security="none" />

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="fullyAuthenticated" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
        ref="siteminderFilter" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SMSESSION"
        invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/Logout.html" />
    <security:session-management
        invalid-session-url="/SessionTimeout.html">
         <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/pages/common/SessionTimeout.html" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
```

And registered an event in web.xml along with session-timeout configuration

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>localDeploymentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I am not sure in what I am missing here. But the url is not getting redirected to the sessiontimeout page.

When I tried to debug the springs code, I saw that only "RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy" is getting called and the new session are getting created using the existing session. I am expecting some code which will redirect to the session expiry URL. But I didnt find any during the debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml should look like :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

        <display-name>Local-Dev Timeout POC</display-name>

    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
            <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
            <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

Your spring config should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <security:http auto-config="true">

            <security:intercept-url pattern="/keep-alive" access="permitAll" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('USER')" />
            <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/denied" />
            <security:session-management>
                    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="10" expired-url="/expired" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
            </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider>
                    <security:user-service>
                            <security:user name="greg" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                    </security:user-service>
            </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.isban" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
            <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
            <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>
```

If they're not logged in, because the session has expired, they will be redirected to login.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have all this configuration in my web.xml and spring security. I have updated the contents thatthe same in my question now. Please check once